# How to Convert datetime value to yyyymmddhhmmss in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, datetime-format

How to convert `datetime` value to `yyyymmddhhmmss`?

for example 
 From  `2014-04-17 13:55:12`

To    `20140417135512`

Comment: May this SO Answer will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19506225/convert-datetime-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-in-sql-server

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Since SQL Server Version 2012 you can use:

```
SELECT format(getdate(),'yyyyMMddHHmmssffff')
```

Comment: This simplifies my life so much!

Answer (score 22):

This seems to work:

```
declare @d datetime
set @d = '2014-04-17 13:55:12'

select replace(convert(varchar(8), @d, 112)+convert(varchar(8), @d, 114), ':','')
```

Result:

```
20140417135512
```

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, getdate(), 112), 126), '-', ''), 'T', ''), ':', '')
```

Answer (score 7):

`FORMAT()` is slower than `CONVERT().`
This answer is slightly better than @jpx's answer because it only does a replace on the time part of the date.

Format 112 = yyyymmdd - no format change needed

Format 108 = hh:mm:ss - so replace is used to remove the :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 112) + 
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 108), ':', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option I have googled, but contains several replace ...

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(19), CONVERT(DATETIME, getdate(), 112), 126), '-', ''), 'T', ''), ':', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

This query is to convert the `DateTimeOffset` into the format `yyyyMMddhhss` with Offset. I have replaced the hyphens, `colon(:), period(.)` from the data, and kept the hyphen for the seperation of Offset from the `DateTime`.

```
SELECT REPLACE(SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(33),SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),126), 1, 8), '-', '') +
SUBSTRING(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 126),'T',''),'.',''),':',''),9,DATALENGTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(33), SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(), 126)))
```

Answer (score 0):

also this works too

```
SELECT replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar, getdate(), 120),':',''),'-',''),' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

**20090320093349**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date,112) + 
LEFT(REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,@date,114),':',''),6)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low-quality. Your answer is likely to be deleted if you don't edit it so as to add an explanation.