# If Null, then HOLD the Previous non-Null Value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-null

I am using SQL Server.  I want to replace all NULLS in a table with the previous (last) non-null value in order to fill the NULL gaps in the data.  For example, let's say I have a table where some values are NULL:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE(
        dt datetime2(0),
        v1 INT,
        v2 INT,
        v3 INT,
        v4 INT,
        v5 INT,
        v999 INT
)

INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:45', 3, 4, 8, 5, NULL, 2
INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:46', 9, NULL, 2, NULL, 1, 0
INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:47', 5, 2, NULL, 7, 8, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:48', 9, 0, NULL, 6, 6, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:49', NULL, 7, 0, 0, 3, NULL
INSERT INTO @Table (dt,v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v999) SELECT '6/12/2021 03:50', 6, 2, 7, 3, NULL, NULL
```

Table:

[image: table]

But pretend that I have about 2 million rows and about 200 columns.

I have tried SELECT statements for each column but it is incredibly slow.  I have also tried using an UPDATE statement (which also uses SELECT) and it is very slow.  I couldn't find a good alternative to the LAST_VALUE and IGNORE NULLS for SQL Server.  Do you have any ideas on how to replace the NULLS with the last non-null value for a lot of rows and columns?

Edit: I expect the result to look like this, where the previous non-null value would fill down for any calculated null values for each column:

[image: result]

I tried Update statements for each column but the query is very slow.  They were something like this, but I tried several kinds.  All of the attempts using a Select were very slow.

```
UPDATE #table SET v1 = (SELECT TOP 1 u.v1 FROM #table u WHERE u.v1 is not null AND u.dt <= #table.dt ORDER BY u.dt DESC)
```

Edit #2: edited for clarity of question as I am looking to "hold the last non-value" across the NULL gaps in the column.

Comment: Please share the select and update statements you tried. Please also share your expected results. Would column `v1`'s NULL value for row 5 be replaced by `6`?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Updated to show expected results and example of an update/select statement.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple, cheap way to do this.  Part of the problem is your data model.  It is highly suspicious to have so many columns.  And, even worse, they seem to have similar data.  They should probably be stored in different rows.

What can you do?  Well, you could do:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             first_value(v1) over (order by (case when v1 is not null then 1 else 2 end), dt desc) as last_v1,
             first_value(v2) over (order by (case when v2 is not null then 1 else 2 end), dt desc) as last_v2,
             . . .
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set v1 = coalesce(v1, last_v1),
        v2 = coalesce(v2, last_v2),
        . . . ;
```

I caution you that updating all the rows in a large table takes a long time.  But this is a relatively simple way to express the query.

Note that SQL Server does have limits on the number of columns in a query or result set, so this won't work on an arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  However, I do not get the expected result when I try this query.  It looks like it is filling in all NULL values with the last non-null received.  My original question may have been unclear.  I am looking to fill in the NULL values with the last non-null "at an earlier minute" so it is filling forward across any NULL gaps with the previous non-null value.

Comment: @Enriq . . . This does exactly what your question asks:  "I want to replace all NULLS in a table with the last non-null value in the column. "  Based on your comment, the question is poorly phrased.

Comment: Yes, the question was poorly phrased.

Answer (score 0):

I have continued to look into this problem and to come up with a solution.  Here is something that appears to work with the example table.

I found the start of the solution on a blog by Tomaž Kaštrun.  He provides an explanation of a method to replace all NULL values with the last non-NULL value.

https://tomaztsql.wordpress.com/2018/08/05/filling-propagading-empty-values-with-last-nonnull-value-using-t-sql/

Tomaž references a clever solution called "The Last non NULL Puzzle" written by Itzik Ben-Gan.  It provides Solution 2 for Using Concatenation and a Window Function.  The key is to convert the date into a binary number that conserves the order of the columns.  I don't understand it completely but it works.

https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle

Since my date is not in smalldatetime format, I had to convert my date format into a value that preserves the order in order for it to work.  I found a post on stackoverflow that explains how to force the date into an date + time int.

[How to Convert datetime value to yyyymmddhhmmss in SQL server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23133860/how-to-convert-datetime-value-to-yyyymmddhhmmss-in-sql-server)

Combining all of these techniques, I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT
dt,
replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') as dt_value,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v1 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v1_nonull,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v2 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v2_nonull,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v3 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v3_nonull,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v4 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v4_nonull,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v5 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v5_nonull,

CAST(SUBSTRING(MAX(CAST(replace(convert(varchar(8), dt, 112)+convert(varchar(8), dt, 114), ':','') AS BINARY(32)) + 
     CAST(v999 AS BINARY(12))) 
     OVER( ORDER BY dt ASC ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING ),33, 12) AS INT) 
         AS v999_nonull

FROM @Table
ORDER BY dt
```

And the result is below.  I have not tested this on my full table but the results look favorable.

[image]